# How to solve 'ambiguous import' when using go mod?

Tags: go

I'm trying to run go-ethereum@v1.0.0 on my windows machine.

What I do:

```
cd G:\go
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git
cd go-ethereum/cmd/geth
git checkout tags/v1.0.0 -b v1.0.0
go mod init github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth
go run .
```

I hope go mod can help me install all modules, but meet an error:

```
package github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth: unknown import path "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth": ambiguous import: found github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth in multiple modules:
        github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth (G:\go\go-ethereum\cmd\geth)
        github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum v1.8.23 (G:\GOPATH\pkg\mod\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum@v1.8.23\cmd\geth)
```

I think that's because the cmd/geth exists in $GOPATH and $PWD both. How can I solve this can run successfully?

PS: I hope it use $PWD so that I can change it.

Comment: just delete `G:\GOPATH\pkg\mod\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum@v1.8.23` folder

Comment: @beiping96 It will reinstall it automatically when run go build

Comment: You should ask the go-etherum designers. Adding a go.mod is not going to work. Checkout the version you need an populate your GOPATH with the relevant packages in the right version.

Comment: @Volker That is not a go-etherum problem. Let me abstract it: When using go mod, clone the repo out of GOPATH. The repo imports some package in itself. When run go build, it install a new repication in GOPATH, but not using that I cloned.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to geth, do this. I did this.

```
cd $GOPATH/src
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
git checkout tags/v1.0.0 -b v1.0.0
go install github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth
ls $GOPATH/bin/geth
```